# How to define a title page

Tags: graphics, covers

I am very new to LaTeX. Now I am trying to define the cover page of my document. It currently consists of the title and a single picture.

I have tried

```
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[height=100mm]{../images/dragon.jpg}
\end{figure}
\end{titlepage}
```

But this still does not place the image and title on the same page. Moreover, I would like to define a set of objects to belong to the cover page and they to be resized and positioned as deemed fit. That is, I wouldn't like to care about absolute sizes of pictures.

How can I define a set of objects, that compose the cover page?

Comment: In this context, it doesn't make sense to use `figure`, which has the 'authority' to move your image where it sees fit. Just use a `center` environment with`\includegraphics`.  And use `height=.8\textwidth` or something similar.  (There a bunch of other predefined lengths you can use; see `texdoc geometry`.)

Comment: Have a look at the [`titling`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titling) package.

Comment: See http://ctan.org/topic/titlepage. http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/info/latex-samples/TitlePages/titlepages.pdf includes some nice examples. I found it useful as a starting point when I needed to do something like this. http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/titling/titling.pdf is the package mentioned by @GonzaloMedina. It is extremely flexible and very useful. I've no experience with http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlepic/titlepic-manual.pdf but it does apparently support images in titlepages.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you use documentclass `book`, you can try as a start:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\newcommand{\bigsize}{\fontsize{35pt}{20pt}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.1\textwidth]{logo}\\[1cm]
{\bigsize The Book}\\
My Name \\
{\today}\\[1cm]
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{logo}
\end{titlepage}
\chapter{My Big Book}
\end{document}
```

Note, I have used the demo mode option on graphicx. Please also use the search function on this page. With your keywords you can find some terrific advice. ShareLaTeX Blog has [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/08/09/thesis-series-pt5.html#.UvZTbV6ef5f) a verry nice post about the topic. And some more advice about: Basic Structure, Page Layout, Figures, Subfigures and Tables, Bibliographies with Biblatex

Comment: Why `\fontsize{35pt}{20pt}`? The baselineskip should be bigger than the font size.

Comment: @ egreg I have the rule applied so, because I have no deeper insights. I am pleased to learn something from you. Feel free to edit the code accordingly.

Comment: The first argument of `\fontsize` takes, roughly speaking, the letter height and the second argument takes the skip from one to the next baseline. Furthermore you should use `\par` or an empty line to add the line breaks because otherwise the baselineskip can be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

[image: titling 1]

To use the `titling` package you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titling,graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\zapfstyle}{%
    \fontencoding{T1}%
    \fontseries{mb}%
    \fontshape{it}%
    \fontfamily{pzc}%
    \selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textzf}{\zapfstyle}
\title{MY BOOK}
\author{My Self}
\date{266 \textsc{bce}}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlingpage}
  \begin{center}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \includegraphics[width=.75\textwidth]{example-image-a}\bigskip
    \vspace*{\fill}\vspace*{\fill}\par
    {\Huge\zapfstyle \thetitle\bigskip\par}
    {\Huge\zapfstyle \theauthor\bigskip\par}
    {\LARGE \thedate\bigskip\bigskip\par}
  \end{center}
    {\large Perfect Publishing\hspace*{\fill}Forward by Fabulous Freddy\smallskip\\
    The World\hspace*{\fill}Author of \emph{Kayaking with dragons}}
\end{titlingpage}
\end{document}
```

By setting the image width using a proportion of `\textwidth`, you could substitute another image relatively easily. It might be better in that case to do

```
\includegraphics[width=.75\textwidth,height=.5\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
```

This will prevent the width exceeding 3/4 of the text width and the height exceeding 1/2 of the text height but will keep the image proportioned correctly.

`titlingpage` is one environment offered by `titling` but there are others. Whereas `titlingpage` would still allow you to use `maketitle`, `titlepage` does not. Moreover, you might simply customise the behaviour of a simple `\maketitle`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titling,graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\zapfstyle}{%
    \fontencoding{T1}%
    \fontseries{mb}%
    \fontshape{it}%
    \fontfamily{pzc}%
    \selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textzf}{\zapfstyle}
\setlength{\droptitle}{25pt}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{%
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=.75\textwidth]{example-image-a}\bigskip\par
    \vskip 5em
  \end{center}}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\Huge\zapfstyle}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 1em}
\preauthor{\begin{center}\Huge\zapfstyle}
\postauthor{\par\end{center}\vskip 2.5em}
\predate{\begin{center}\LARGE}
\postdate{\par\end{center}\vskip 2.5em}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookd}{%
  \large\noindent Perfect Publishing\hspace*{\fill}Forward by Fabulous Freddy\smallskip\\
    The World\hspace*{\fill}Author of \emph{Kayaking with dragons}}

\title{MY BOOK}
\author{My Self}
\date{266 \textsc{bce}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: titling 2]