# Making cover page of a report; I want to put title below image

Tags: graphics

Below is my LaTeX code, I want it to continue the title under image, but, unfortunately, it continues to the next page and leaves a big space at the first page. How can I fix this.?

```
    \documentclass{report}

    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{titlepage}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{upm.png}
    \title{COMBINATORICS:- \\ Combination and Permutation in Statistics Application}
    \maketitle
    \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}


    \end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use `\maketitle` if making your own title page using the `titlepage` environment. Also, your example is missing a `\begin{center}`, but `\centering` would be preferable instead.

Comment: The `titling` package can be helpful. It is designed to customise the `\maketitle` command.

Comment: @Bernard But `titling`'s `\maketitle` is no more suitable. I think the OP wants either `titlepage` or `titling`'s `titlingpage` (if I remember the name of the environment correctly).

Comment: @Bernard Is `titling` buggy or is it intended that `\maketitle` can only be used in a `titlingpage` environment if `\maketitle` typesets the first output on the page?

Comment: See my answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159407/39222) for the use of `titling`.

Comment: @cfr: I advised to take a look at the titling package mainly  because of its `\pre…`, `\post…` and the `\maketitlehook`s commands.

Comment: @Bernard Oh, I see. Yes, you are certainly right about that - `titling` makes customising `\maketitle` really straightforward. But one of `titlepage` or `titlingpage` might be even more helpful, here. (Though I don't know how much difference `titling` makes in this case as opposed to just using `titlepage` in a standard class?)

Comment: @cfr: In my opinion, using titlepage amounts to having to reinvent the wheel. With titling I feel things being structured. But maybe I'm wrong, and it's only a problem of my psyche, as would say Dr Freud.

Comment: @Bernard Hmm... I'm just not sure `\maketitle` is designed for this. I thought that was why the package provided the two environments as well? But maybe I'm wrong about this...