# titling (pkg): bug or feature? (\maketitle in titlingpage works only if first text in page)

Tags: titling

The `titling` package allows users to customise the appearance of the document title, to include multiple titles etc. In addition to allowing customisation of `\maketitle`, it defines a new environment, `titlingpage`, which is similar to `titlepage` but allows the use of `\maketitle` within the environment to typeset the title, author, date etc.

Here's an example based on code from page 5 of the manual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
  \begin{titlingpage}
    \setlength{\droptitle}{30pt}% lower the title
    \maketitle
    A few words\dots
    \begin{abstract}A few more words\dots\end{abstract}
  \end{titlingpage}
\end{document}
```

[image: <code>titlingpage</code> environment]

In trying to answer [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/188296/39222), I tried to use `titlingpage` to typeset the title *below* an image to be typeset first. When this failed, I produced the following modification of the above example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
  \begin{titlingpage}
    A few words\dots
    \setlength{\droptitle}{30pt} % lower the title
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}A few more words\dots\end{abstract}
  \end{titlingpage}
\end{document}
```

[image: bug or feature?]

Not what I expected based on the documentation....

Obviously, it is possible to use `titlingpage`, like `titlepage`, to typeset the title below other things here. But I cannot figure out how to do so ***using `\maketitle`***.

Is this a bug or a feature? Either way, is there a workaround? (If a feature, is this a bug in the documentation?!)

Note that on page 4, the manual says that it defines `\maketitle` 'essentially' as follows:

```
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
\vspace*{\droptitle}
\maketitlehooka
{\pretitle \title \posttitle}
\maketitlehookb
{\preauthor \author \postauthor}
\maketitlehookc
{\predate \date \postdate}
\maketitlehookd
}
```

So, again, nothing to suggest that `\maketitle` will itself start a new page - especially in the `titlingpage` environment.

I'm assuming this is not really how it is defined. (And, indeed, the actual code when the `titlepage` option is not active and the document is in one-column mode includes a suspicious-looking `newpage`...)

It seems to me that `titlingpage` ought to do something like

```
\let\oldnewpage\newpage
\let\newpage\relax
```

and

```
\let\newpage\oldnewpage
```

at the beginning and end of the environment if `titlingpage` is to work as advertised. (But I'm sure this particular suggestion would either not work at all or have horrible side-effects or both.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suspected, the problem comes from `\newpage`, not just one of them but two `\newpage`s are responsible here for the mentioned behaviour.

This is the definition of `\maketitle` contained in `titling.sty`:

```
\providecommand{\maketitle}{}
\if@titlepage
  \renewcommand{\maketitle}{\begin{titlepage}%
    \let\footnotesize\small
    \let\footnoterule\relax
    \let \footnote \thanks
    \@bsmarkseries
      \def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\@textsuperscript{%
         \normalfont\@bsthanksheadpre \tamark \@bsthanksheadpost}}}%
      \long\def\@makefntext##1{\makethanksmark ##1}
    \null\vfil
    \vskip 60\p@
    \vspace*{\droptitle}
    \maketitlehooka
    {\@bspretitle \@title \@bsposttitle}
    \maketitlehookb
    {\@bspreauthor \@author \@bspostauthor}
    \maketitlehookc
    {\@bspredate \@date \@bspostdate}
    \maketitlehookd
    \par
    \@thanks
    \vfil\null
    \end{titlepage}%
    \@bscontmark  %  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
%%%    \@bsmtitlempty
  } % end titlepage defs
\else
  \renewcommand{\maketitle}{\par
    \begingroup
      \@bsmarkseries
      \def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\@textsuperscript{%
         \normalfont\@bsthanksheadpre \tamark \@bsthanksheadpost}}}%
      \long\def\@makefntext##1{\makethanksmark ##1}
      \if@twocolumn
        \ifnum \col@number=\@ne
          \@maketitle
        \else
          \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
        \fi
      \else
        \newpage
        \global\@topnum\z@
        \@maketitle
      \fi
      \thispagestyle{plain}\@thanks
    \endgroup
    \@bscontmark  %  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
%%%    \@bsmtitlempty
  } % end non-titlepage

  \def\@maketitle{%
    \newpage
    \null
    \vskip 2em%
          \vspace*{\droptitle}
    \maketitlehooka
    {\@bspretitle \@title \@bsposttitle}
    \maketitlehookb
    {\@bspreauthor \@author \@bspostauthor}
    \maketitlehookc
    {\@bspredate \@date \@bspostdate}
    \maketitlehookd
    \par
    \vskip 1.5em}
\fi
```

Basically, we have a conditional test for `@titlepage`; since in your case this is false (`article.cls` sets `\@titlepagefalse` by default), we can go to the `\else` part which redefines `\maketitle` which, if two-column mode is not active (as it is by default), has a `\newpage`:

```
      \else
        \newpage
        \global\@topnum\z@
        \@maketitle
      \fi
```

before calling `\@maketitle` which in its turn is defined by

```
  \def\@maketitle{%
    \newpage
    \null
    \vskip 2em%
          \vspace*{\droptitle}
    \maketitlehooka
    {\@bspretitle \@title \@bsposttitle}
    \maketitlehookb
    {\@bspreauthor \@author \@bspostauthor}
    \maketitlehookc
    {\@bspredate \@date \@bspostdate}
    \maketitlehookd
    \par
    \vskip 1.5em}
```

which has another `\newpage` command. Those are responsible for the behaviour you noticed.

To avoid this, one possibility is to patch `\maketitle` *and* `\@maketitle` to suppress the `\newpage`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}
 {\newpage}
 {}
 {}
 {}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
 {\newpage}
 {}
 {}
 {}
\makeatother

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
  \begin{titlingpage}
    A few words\dots
    \setlength{\droptitle}{30pt} % lower the title
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}A few more words\dots\end{abstract}
  \end{titlingpage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Standard classes have the `\newpage` in the definition of `\@maketitle`, so I guess the author of the package kept this as a feature, though your example use perhaps suggests that these `\newpage`s commands would be better left as optional and not hard-coded.

Comment: Thanks. That's was the suspicious `\newpage` I mentioned. Note that this is not specific to `article`, though. The same happens with `book` and `report`. Do you think the behaviour is intentional, then, and the documentation buggy? Or is the code intentional but not this effect? Or neither?

Comment: Of course, the case of `book` or `report` will trigger the `titlepage` environment which will start a new page. But is this intended given the description of `titlingpage` and `\maketitle` in the manual? The code makes it look clearly intended but I'm not quite sure why it would be given the purpose of `titlingpage`.

Comment: @cfr In my optinion the `\newpage`s commands (I updated my answer showing that there are really two of them involved here) were intentional (as apparently they try to emulate the behaviour of the original definitions in standard classes), but perhaps the package should somehow make them optional and not hard-coded.

Comment: I agree that the `\newpage`s are intentional in a sense but I'm not sure that their *effect* in `titlingpage` is. Just before introducing that environment, the manual says `Do not use \maketitle within the titlepage environment as it will start yet another page.` The next paragraph then begins `The titlingpage environment falls between the titlepage option and the titlepage environment. Within the titlingpage environment you can use the \maketitle command, and any others you wish.` It seems an odd description if the effect is intended as a feature...

Comment: @cfr Yes, I agree that the documentation should be more clear in this regard and should mention the effect of the `\newpage`s. I have the impression that the package author assumed users are familiar with the behaviour of `\maketitle` from the standard classes and wanted to follow the `\newpage` feature.

Comment: Huh. I'd always assumed (especially given the explanation of the package's definition of `\maketitle`) that the whole point of `titlingpage` was precisely to turn that particular aspect of the standard definitions off. (That is, I was familiar with that effect in the standard definitions but the documentation I took to imply that `titling` altered it for the `titlingpage` environment specifically. That kind of seemed the point of the environment...) But I guess you are right and I must have misunderstood the intended meaning.

Comment: @cfr Now I'm tired and have to get some sleep: Tomorrow I'll have a closer look to the documentation. In any case I agree that the "essential" description of `\maketitle` contained there can be misleading since it doen's mention the `\newpage`.